# Config file with IDE settings for commit

Tags: phpstorm

I use .editorconfig file (http://editorconfig.org/) for set basic editor settings for project.
I commit it in repo and all developers shared these settings.

But there are more specific settings.
For example, IDE aks me: "do you want, I'll compile your TypeScript files?".
And I answer: "No! No way! I use webpack for it. I don't need any garbage in my source directory."
Or "Composer update, maybe? Compile SCSS to CSS?", "No! No!".

But other developers may accidentally say "Yes".

Can I somehow create a config file for this that I can commit to repo?
Folder .idea contains these settings, but also contains a lot of extra things (not for share).

Comment: Unlikely -- such stuff is usually stored in `workspace.xml` which is user-specific and should not be committed in VCS in any case. Most of the stuff from `.idea` subfolder can be shared though (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems)

Comment: For reference purposes (same on PhpStorm forums) : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000709444-Config-file-with-IDE-settings-for-commit